# ORACLE: need to export table data without spaces between columns

Tags: oracle, bash, unix, import, export

Say i have Table A with columns

```
      col1   col2   col3   col4
      -------------------
      sajal  singh  28     IND
      hello  how    are    you
```

I want to export the data into a flat file without spaces or tabs between columns
So the output should be

```
      cat dump
      sajalsingh28IND
      hellohowareyou
```

what i have tried. i have written a script

```
      #!/usr/bin/bash

      #the file where sql output will go
      OUT=report.txt
      >$OUT
      DESC=desc.txt
      >$DESC

      sqlplus -s "xxx/xxx@xxx" << END_SQL > /dev/null

      set pages 0
      set feedback off
      set heading off
      set trimspool off
      set termout off
      set verify off
      set wrap off

      SPOOL $DESC

      Select * from table_name;

      SPOOL OFF

      END_SQL
```

But i am getting outputs of one row in multiple lines and with tabs/spaces

1. So question is how can i fix that? and
2. I found some data pump utilities like expdp. Can i use that in Unix? if yes, how can i acheive the dump in that format?

Thank You

Comment: Maybe this sound stupid but I useally solve this with notepad ++, where i delete all the comma and space with replace all, and its really good and very fast. however, Maybe you need something automated

Comment: Thanks Moudiz. but i have to put this in production for multiple tables :) so i guess notepadd++ wont work out for me .

Comment: Are you sure you don't even want the values paded out to the column length? I can't see what you could do with the file - it would be impossible to interptet the contents, surely?

Comment: Alex, values padded out to column length would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what i came up with: it will dump oracle data without any spaces etc between columns, while preserving the spaces within data. I thought i would share it with you.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#the file where sql output will go
OUT=report.txt
>$OUT
DESC=desc.txt
>$DESC

TABLE_NAME=$1


###GET DESCRIBE####

s=""
#######################
sqlplus -s "xxx/xxx@xxx" << END_SQL > /dev/null

set pages 0
set feedback off
set heading off
set trimspool off
set termout off
set verify off
set wrap off

SPOOL $DESC

desc $TABLE_NAME;

SPOOL OFF

END_SQL
#######################

for i in `cat $DESC|awk -F" " '{print $1}'|grep -v -i name|grep -v -`
do
s=$s"trim($i)||'|'||"
done

s=`echo $s|sed "s/||'|'||$//g"`
echo $s

#######################
#sqlplus - silent mode
#redirect /dev/null so that output is not shown on terminal
sqlplus -s "xxx/xxx@xxx" << END_SQL > /dev/null

set pages 0
set feedback off
set heading off
set trimspool off
set termout off
set verify off
set colsep ""
set tab off
set lines 1500

SPOOL $OUT

select $s from $TABLE_NAME;
SPOOL OFF

END_SQL
#######################


cat $OUT|sed "s/|//g"|sed "s/ *$//g" >$OUT.new
mv $OUT.new $OUT

echo Finished writing report $OUT
```

Answer (score 5):

If you already have a CSV dump, then you can run the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=""}{$1=$1}1' csv.dump > new.dump
```

#### Untested:

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SPOOL $DESC

SELECT col1 ||''|| col2 ||''|| col3 FROM table_name;

SPOOL OFF;
```

Comment: no. I dont have a csv. if you see the opening comments i tried to show a simplified oracle table. since i cant show an actual one here. sorry for the confusion.i edited my question

Comment: @user2404176 No worries. I have added an update to the answer. Not tested though.

Answer (score 3):

From a "simplified oracle view" to "plain" characters with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -n '3,$ s/\s//gp' file
```

```
$cat file
      col1   col2   col3   col4
      -------------------
      sajal  singh  28     IND
      hello  how    are    you
$sed -n '3,$ s/\s//gp' file
sajalsingh28IND
hellohowareyou
```

Explanation: replace all white space (not line breaks) from line 3 to EOF with "nothing".

Comment: OP doesn't have a CSV dump.

Comment: thank you. i think i have confused many by writing simplified view. I have a table in the DB. I dont have it in a file. my apologies for the confusion. i edited my question. please have a look again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the columns padded out but no *additional* spaces between the columns you can do:

```
set colsep ""
```

The default is to have a single space between the double-quotes, which puts a single space between the columns. You might also want to do:

```
set tab off
```

... to ensure that multiple spaces in the padding isn't converted to tabs, which looks fine for display but would be a pain parsing the file.

If you want no spaces at all, to do this within SQL*Plus you'd need to concatenate the columns:

```
 select col1 || col2 || col3 || col4 from table_name;
```

This is useful if you're putting a delimiter between the columns (e.g. making it a CSV), but I don't know what you'd be able to do with the data in the file if you squashed everything together without delimiters.

Comment: yes i know it sounds crazy. this data is to be passed to mainframes who dont understand delims! :)

Comment: @user2404176 - fixed-width columns with no spaces between doesn't sound crazy; variable width with no delimiters (as in your initial example) does as it appears to be unparsable. Unless there are already markers in the values, I suppose.

Comment: great ! this is working! just one issue. when i openthe spool file, i see that a record wraps to the next line halfway through the screen. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: i agree a 100 percent. unfortunately i cant reveal the purpose. But you re Absolutely right Alex.

Comment: @user2404176 - `set linesize` to something big.